# On Ubuntu wheezy/sid running Gnome how to I move a window partially off the screen?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, off-screen

When I click on another window the moved window springs back to its previous location, so it's fully visible in the current desktop.  I don't need to see it all the time, I just need to be able to grab part of its title bar so I can drag it back.

Yes, this falls in the category of another upgrade-caused loss of functionality I've enjoyed since the '90s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://earlruby.org/2012/04/getting-rid-of-self-resizing-windows-in-ubuntu-linux-12-04/

In a nutshell, from the above page:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
Applications > System Tools > Preferences > CompizConfig Settings Manager
Click "Window Management"
Uncheck “Place Windows”.
Click the Grid word (not the Grid checkbox -- leave it checked)
Select the Edges tab and change all Resize Actions to “None”.
```